# Any one knows why I cant print the content of a variable that contains files from a folder? (Expected expression on "!ls" expression)

Tags: python, tensorflow, expression, google-colaboratory

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Ruta raiz
PATH="/content/drive/MyDrive/Flores"

#Datos de entrada
INPATH="/content/drive/MyDrive/Flores/processed"

#Datos de salida
OUTPATH=PATH+'/test/'

# Ruta de checkpoints
CKPATH=PATH+'/checkpoints'

imgurls = !ls -1 "{INPATH}"

imgurls
```

This is the Output

`['JPEG']`

On the path I have such a lot of files (924 to be exact)

[Im getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpFqv.png)

Im expecting to get the name of the files that are on the root.

Comment: `"{INPATH}"` is a literal string.  It does not use the INPATH variable at all.  Did you mean to make that an f-string?

Comment: `!` isn't python syntax. It's an extension some REPLs add, like IPython Notebook, but it doesn't work in normal Python code. Use `os.listdir(INPATH)` when you want to get a list of files in a specific directory.

Comment: (The other thing is that `ls` itself isn't designed, or reliable, for programmatic use; see [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) on the Wooledge bash wiki).

Comment: And your error should be **in the text of the question**, not as an image link. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)